# Why does this query give an empty set when formatting dates with MySQL Database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, date-format

Why this query Gives empty set with 3 warnings?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Productions 
WHERE date_prod=DATE_FORMAT('01/01/2012','%Y/%m/%d');
```

this is what in the Productions Table.

```
+-------------+------------+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| numlotfdg   | date_prod  | Dur_Prod | Dur_trns | Dur_ins | t0                  | tc                  | texp                | nbrdoses |
+-------------+------------+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| FG-111204B1 | 2011-12-04 |      180 |       70 |      30 | 2011-12-04 06:20:00 | 2011-12-04 10:30:00 | 2011-12-04 16:30:00 |        6 |
| FG-111227B1 | 2011-12-27 |      180 |       50 |      30 | 2011-12-27 06:40:00 | 2011-12-27 10:00:00 | 2011-12-27 16:45:00 |       18 |
| FG-120101B1 | 2012-01-01 |        0 |       70 |      30 | 2012-01-01 06:20:00 | 2012-01-01 10:30:00 | 2012-01-01 16:30:00 |        6 |
+-------------+------------+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm using a French OS (Windows XP) and we use this date format: `DD/MM/YYYY`

and this is the Java Code i'm using to fill the JTable

```
"select * from Productions where date_prod=STR_TO_DATE('"+jTextField2.getText()+"','%Y-%m-%d')"
```

The Table Structure

```
create table Productions(numlotfdg varchar(100) primary key,
                        date_prod Date,
                        Dur_Prod int,
                        Dur_trns int,
                        Dur_ins int ,
                        t0 Timestamp,
                        tc TimeStamp,
                        texp Timestamp,
                        nbrdoses int);
```

Comment: Beware SQL injection in your Java code... Seriously, use `PreparedStatement`s.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to compare only against the date portion of `DATETIME`.  Don't use `DATE_FORMAT()` in the `WHERE` clause, because you need to use MySQL's internal date format YYYY-MM-DD there:

```
/* Truncate the DATETIME field to only its date for comparison */
/* And use the format YYYY-MM-DD in the WHERE clause */
select * from Productions where DATE(date_prod) = '2012-01-01';
```

Alternatively, [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) can convert the date to the correct format in  MySQL, rather than doing it application-side in Java.

```
select * from Productions where DATE(date_prod) = STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2012', '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Comment: @Papa_Jay Then use `STR_TO_DATE()` as I have added above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
select * from Productions where DATE(convert(datetime, data_prod)) = '01/01/2012'
```

Comment: Does `select DATE(date_prod) from Productions` work properly?

Comment: Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Comment: Ok, one more edit, did it work? If not, does `select DATE(convert(datetime, date_prod)) from Productions` work properly?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) like this

```
select * from Productions where date_prod=STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2012','%d/%m/%y');
```

and see if this works

Comment: Nope , it gives Empty set, 1 warning (0.05 sec)